# R - Add data from another dataframe based on two criteria

Tags: r, replace

I'm trying to add data from another dataframe to another, based on two matching criteria.

The first dataframe is as follows:

```
df.1<-cbind.data.frame(c("Site A","Site A","Site A","Site A","Site B","Site B","Site B","Site C","Site C"),c("Species 1","Species 2","Species 3","Species 5","Species 2","Species 3","Species 4","Species 1","Species 5"),c(10,15,5,10,30,10,20,10,5))
names(df.1)<-c("Location","Species","Count")
```

Which gives:

```
Location  Species    Count
Site A    Species 1  10
Site A    Species 2  15
Site A    Species 3   5
Site A    Species 5  10
Site B    Species 2  30
Site B    Species 3  10
Site B    Species 4  20
Site C    Species 1  10
Site C    Species 5   5
```

My second dataframe is:

```
df.2<-as.data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=5))
names(df.2)<-c("Species 1","Species 2","Species 3","Species 4","Species 5")
row.names(df.2)<-c("Site A","Site B","Site C")
```

Which gives:

```
       Species 1  Species 2  Species 3 Species 4 Species 5
Site A  0          0          0         0         0
Site B  0          0          0         0         0
Site C  0          0          0         0         0
```

I would like to add the Counts from the first dataframe to the second one, based on location and species. It should look like this:

```
       Species 1  Species 2  Species 3 Species 4 Species 5
Site A  10         15         5         0         10
Site B  0          30         10        20        0
Site C  10         0          0         0         15
```

I can't seem to do it though. The problem seems to lie in the fact that the two dataframes are different sizes.

I.e. I tried:

```
df.2<-ifelse(row.names(df.2)==df.1$Location && names(df.2)==df.1$Species,df.1$Count,0)
```

But get the following error:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>   2: In `==.default`(names(df.2), df.1$Species) :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Does anyone have a solution to this? Or at least some guidance of a suitable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or w/ base R

```
tapply(df.1$Count,list(df.1$Location,df.1$Species),"[")

       Species 1 Species 2 Species 3 Species 4 Species 5
Site A        10        15         5        NA        10
Site B        NA        30        10        20        NA
Site C        10        NA        NA        NA         5
```

If you don't want NAs

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your second data frame, simply spread your `Species` column into wide format, for example using `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
df.1 %>%
   spread(Species, Count) %>%
   mutate_all(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))


  Location Species 1 Species 2 Species 3 Species 4 Species 5
1   Site A        10        15         5         0        10
2   Site B         0        30        10        20         0
3   Site C        10         0         0         0         5
```

The `mutate_all` function replaces all `NA`s introduced by `spread` with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(Count ~ Location +Species, df.1)
#       Species
#Location Species 1 Species 2 Species 3 Species 4 Species 5    
#  Site A        10        15         5         0        10
#  Site B         0        30        10        20         0
#  Site C        10         0         0         0         5
```